# Making List Box items work like option buttons VBA

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I have a VBA user form with a list box that contains 8 items. Its defined as a multi-select listbox.
Item 2 and item 3 are dependent on each other so they can't both be selected together.
In order to do that I wrote:

```
If ListBox1.Selected(3) = True Then
    ListBox1.Selected(2) = False
ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(2) = True Then
    ListBox1.Selected(3) = False
End If
```

It does work but not very nicely. If I choose item 2 and than item 3 its fine. but if I try to choose item 2 afterwards than I need to unselect item 3 first and than choose item 2. Is there a better way to do that so it may work like option buttons without the need to cancel the selected item before selecting another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question - this isn't trivial with List Box as the Change event doesn't tell you which item has actually changed!

The below works around this by storing which of the two was selected last.

```
'Member fields
Private fListBoxItem2PreviouslySelected As Boolean

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    With ListBox1
        If fListBoxItem2PreviouslySelected Then
            If .Selected(3) Then
                .Selected(2) = False
                fListBoxItem2PreviouslySelected = False
            End If
        Else
            If .Selected(2) Then
                .Selected(3) = False
                fListBoxItem2PreviouslySelected = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

'Just used for testing purposes
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long: For i = 0 To 10: ListBox1.AddItem i: Next
End Sub
```

Comment: it's still work the same to me. Where do I put the first line?:
Private fListBoxItem2PreviouslySelected As Boolean

Comment: @user1040563 the first line goes standalone near the top of the module. Are you sure it doesn't work? I created a new user form, dropped a list box in, set it to MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti then the above runs perfectly allowing either: neither Item 2 nor 3, or: Item 3 but not 2, or: 2 but not 3, or: not 2 and 3. You should also note that Selected() is base 0 so the first item is Selected(0) etc

Comment: It does work! I have put the first line in a wrong place, Thank you!

Comment: @user1040563 variables on their own like that are called "fields" and can be used to store information outside of a procedure so it can be used again later etc. You're welcome - glad it works